# Curious about Mapping over multiple multiple arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, map

To my shame, I have discovered the power of `Map` quite recently and since then I have been using it more and more. But increasingly I find myself trying to use `Map` with multiple arguments but there is no solution for this and I cannot understand why. Can anyone clarify this? What I could like is something like this:

```
Map[#1+#2,values for #1,values for #2]
```

What is it about `Map` that cannot achieve what `Table` has?

Cheers

Comment: Look for `MapThread`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MapThread`is what you are looking for I think:

```
MapThread[#1 + #2 + #3 &, {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}, {1, 2, 3}}]
(*{1 + a + x, 2 + b + y, 3 + c + z}*)
```

Comment: I have tried the following `MapThread[#1 + #2 &,Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}], 1]]` but I only get `{2,3}` out of all 100 pairs. Where are the rest?

Comment: @lucian perhaps you need `Transpose[Flatten[...]]`

Comment: HA! I think I get it now! Thank you all!

Comment: @Ulrich it is safe to assume that no parallelization can be done with MapThread?

Comment: @lucian probably yes

Comment: @lucian `Parallelize[
 MapThread[#1 + #2 + #3 &, {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}, {1, 2, 3}}]]` evaluates quite slow without errormessage

Answer (score 5):

Combining your example in the comments and your original intentions, why not try something like this?

```
Map[#[[1]]+ #[[2]] &,Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}], 1]]
```

It seems that it accomplishes your want to use `Map` with multiple arguments.

Comment: this is great! I had no idea I can do this! I wish this was in the documentation, or at least I didn't find it

Answer (score 4):

I prefer `Apply` at level 1

```
#1 + #2 & @@@ Tuples[{Range[5], Range[5]}]
```

`Tuples` is used here to give the same effect as `Table`, but of course you can use any two lists (that are the same length)

```
Thread[{list1,list2}]
```

Just to show this is the same as `Table` (if you add a partition), evaluate this:

```
Block[{dim1=5,apply,table},
  apply=#1+#2&@@@Tuples[{Range[dim1],Range[2,6]}]//Partition[#,dim1]&;
  table=Table[i+j,{i,dim1},{j,2,6}];
  apply===table]
```

Which returns `True`